# How to decorate bazel test output to include github actions groups?

Tags: github-actions, bazel

I want to configure bazel test run in CI in such a way that it will employ [Github Actions Group Workflow commands](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#grouping-log-lines) to group failed tests logs.

I basically want to add `::group:://path/to/my:test` at the start of the test logs and `::endgroup::` at the end.

How can I achieve that?

I tried searching docs and even `bazel help test`, but could not find anything that smells like it might lead to success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to write a shell script like

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "::group::bazel test $TEST_TARGET"

"$@"
ERR=$?

echo "::endgroup::"

exit $ERR
```

And pass path to it via `--run_under` bazel test option.

This will include the required commands inside test log